# Capacitor Filesystem iOS writing to Documents does not persist files after app is deleted

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, vuejs3, capacitor-plugin

I see an old question about saving files on iOS using Capacitor Filesystem, but since then Ionic and Capacitor have been updated. I am writing a file on iOS to Directory.Documents and Directory.ExternalStorage because the Capacitor Filesystem docs say these two locations persist after the app is deleted. On Android, this is the case. I deleted my app and the whatever files and folders I saved in Documents stay.

With iOS, they are removed after the app is deleted. Another weird thing on iOS is that when a file is saved, it creates a folder in Documents with the name of the app, and puts the files there. I can get over that part, but I need the files to persist. Is this a bug? The code is very simple, so I don't think I'm doing anything wrong. But here it is in case.

```
await Filesystem.writefile({
path: 'test.pdf',
data: data, // base64 pdf data
directory: Directory.Documents,
})
```

Any ideas? Is this the expected behavior? Is there another plugin I can use that persists the data on iOS after the app is deleted?